# Regioselectivity in electrophilic aromatic substitution of benzofuran and indole

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds, regioselectivity

Why does benzofuran react preferentially at position 2 when nitrated or formylated, while indole reacts preferentially at position 3 (source: Joule and Mills, *Heterocyclic Chemistry* 5th ed., p 371)?

[image: Partial numbering schemes for benzofuran and indole]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In electrophilic substitution of aromatic systems sigma complexes are typically formed as reaction intermediates.  Let's look at the sigma complexes formed in the reaction of benzofuran and indole with an electrophile ($\ce{NO2+}$) at the 2 and 3 positions and compare their stability.

[image: comparing electrophilic attack at the 2 and 3 positions]

With **both** benzofuran and indole attack at the 2 position produces a sigma complex where the positive charge is nicely stabilized by the benzene ring (**1a** and **1b**) . The stabilization is analogous to that found in a benzyl carbocation.

Attack at the 3 position produces a sigma complex where the positive charge can be stabilized by the lone pair of electrons on the adjacent heteroatom (resonance structures **3a** and **3b**), but **because nitrogen is less electronegative than oxygen we would expect resonance structure 3b to be a bigger contributor than resonance structure 3a**. Therefore we would expect the sigma complex produced upon attack at the 3 position to be more stable in the case of indole than benzofuran.

The **overall result** would then be to produce more of the 3 isomer in the case of indole as compared to benzofuran.